# Fishhouse Punch: Peach Brandy vs Schnapps

Tags: alcohol, drinks

The basic recipe for fish-house punch involves cognac, dark rum, peach brandy, sugar, and lemon. I have peach schnapps, which I rather like. However, this blend is one of the few that I find palatable with this much alcohol in it; much like Long Island Iced Tea, it tastes a lot less boozy than it is. If I substitute peach schnapps for peach brandy, will it throw off the balance of the drink? Or possibly add any unwanted flavors?

ETA: When I went to the store, I discovered Paramount brand "Peach-flavored Brandy". The back of the bottle suggests using it in a Fuzzy Naval, which is one of the drinks I usually make with Peach Schnapps. I kind of wonder if it's just got artificial flavors rather than being distilled from peaches? It's a product of Cleveland, which is near where I live, so I don't know how widely available that brand is.

Comment: I think a trial run is warranted....

Comment: I'm available for a trial run.

Answer (score 3):

What is peach brandy? True peach brandy is really hard to find (and tends to be really expensive). It's brandy distilled from fermented peaches. (It may be unaged - eau de vie - or it may be aged in barrels like regular grape brandy.) Confusingly I think some producers call their schnapps "brandy" and vice-versa.

Anyway, if you substitute peach schnapps for this, your drink may be too sweet - peach schnapps (in my admittedly rather limited experience) tend to be neutral alcohol with added sugar and peach flavoring. It's up to you, though - try it and see. You may just want to add less sugar if you do this.

(If you can't find real peach brandy, it may be interesting to substitute slivovitz - Eastern European plum brandy, which may be aged or not, or some other palinka. It's usually fairly cheap as well.)

Comment: Sorry to hear about your experience, but what you call peach schnapps (pure alcohol with fake aroma) is actually a fake liqueur. What you call peach brandy is actually peach schnapps, made from fermented peaches, unaged. Peach brandy would be made from peach wine and aged, and possibly had a little amount of the same wine added back before aging. I haven't had it (nor peach wine, I don't know who might sell it), but with grapes, the schnapps (slivovitz) tastes different from the brandy.

Comment: I found Paramount Peach-flavored Brandy, which suggests using it in a Fuzzy Naval on the back, which is one of the drinks I usually make with Peach schnapps

Comment: @rumtscho you are correct about European schnapps, but what are usually sold as "schnapps" here in the US are almost always just alcohol, artificial flavor and sugar. For example, peppermint schnapps, green apple schnapps, cinnamon schnapps, etc.

Comment: @Yamikuronue that might work - I haven't heard of that brand. If it's regular brandy with added peach flavoring, it could certainly be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this conundrum, I substituted a 50/50 mix of peach schnapps and VS brandy. Not sure what it's supposed to taste like but it tasted good to me!